# Oct 30, 2023 4:27:27 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0 INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Tags: android-studio, appium

I am getting exception after setting all the variable

Oct 30, 2023 4:27:27 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Please help on the same I have added all the path, appium dependencies and everything I tried desktp, terminal but now even exception is confusing me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the code